# Scroll event using Tag Manager on AMP pages unable to track percentages

Tags: scroll, google-analytics, tags, amp-html

I'm using Google Tag Manager and I configured it to show page scrolling events in Google Analytics for normal pages. It worked perfectly but when I went to configure the AMP pages there was no {{Scroll Depth Threshold}} variable available, which was used on the pages normal. So I used {{Scroll Height}} but in Google Analytics the percentages are not displayed in the Event Label, but some numbers that look like the number of pixels, which makes it impossible to group the pages by scrolled percentage.